# How to check current keyboard language in java

Tags: java, keyboard

is there a way in java to check what is the keyboard language in the current program? 
example:

Chrome : english

Eclipse: english

Skype: spanish

Chrome: english

(i can get the current program by jna -  external library)

thanks very much !

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.im.*;  

public class _Test  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();  
        System.out.println(context.getLocale().toString());  
    }  
}
```