# How do I get keyboard language changes - Java

Tags: java, keyboard

I tried many various methods: InputContext, System.getProperty, and even JNI. But non of them worked. I want to detect when a user changes his/her keyboard language while the app is running. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17151054/3959856

Comment: @JackFlamp I used it, but this method doesn't detect keyboard language changes while the app is running. I tried using a while loop, but it stores the value from app start.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Locale.getDefault()`. That might give you what you need. Check the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for methods on Locale to give you language and stuff

Comment: That's the default OS language. I want the current selected keyboard input language